# T-SQL - JSON Nested Objects - 1 row vs. multiple rows

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql

Here is the table definition:

```
key_en, text_en, html_text_en, key_fr, text_fr, html_text_fr
```

Here is my query:

```
SELECT  
    [key_en] AS 'en.key'
    ,[text_en] AS 'en.text'
    ,[html_text_en] AS 'en.htmltext'
    ,[key_fr] AS 'fr.key'
    ,[text_fr] AS 'fr.text'
    ,[html_text_fr] AS 'fr.htmltext'
FROM [MyContent]
FOR JSON PATH;
```

The result I get as JSON is correct.

```
[
    {
        "en": {
            "key": "key en",
            "text": "text en",
            "htmltext": "html en"
        },
        "fr": {
            "key": "key fr",
            "text": "text fr",
            "htmltext": "html fr"
        }
    },
    {
        "en": {
            "key": "key2 en",
            "text": "text2 en",
            "htmltext": "html2 en"
        },
        "fr": {
            "key": "key2 fr",
            "text": "text2 fr",
            "htmltext": "html2 fr"
        }
    }
]
```

However the result set is in a single row (very long string).

I'd like to spread the result set across as many rows as the data in the table. The expected result should be:

```
    ROW 1 
    {
        "en": {
            "key": "key en",
            "text": "text en",
            "htmltext": "html en"
        },
        "fr": {
            "key": "key fr",
            "text": "text fr",
            "htmltext": "html fr"
        }
    }

    ROW 2 
    {
        "en": {
            "key": "key2 en",
            "text": "text2 en",
            "htmltext": "html2 en"
        },
        "fr": {
            "key": "key2 fr",
            "text": "text2 fr",
            "htmltext": "html2 fr"
        }
    }
```

What changes do I have to bring to reach my goal?

Comment: Can you post the expected result for one row? Thanks.

Comment: I just edited my question.

Comment: Probably `FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER` will help. I think that the answers are correct.

Comment: Yes, using that parameter on Martin's answer works. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this modified query which will return a row of JSON per row of your table:

```
SELECT  (
        SELECT  [key_en] AS 'en.key',
                [text_en] AS 'en.text',
                [html_text_en] AS 'en.htmltext',
                [key_fr] AS 'fr.key',
                [text_fr] AS 'fr.text',
                [html_text_fr] AS 'fr.htmltext'
          FOR JSON PATH
        )
  FROM  [MyContent]
```

Comment: Your solution returns an array per row. It should be an array of rows. I have updated my question to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apply`:

```
SELECT j.j
FROM [MyContent] c CROSS APPLY
     (SELECT c.[key_en] AS 'en.key',
             c.[text_en] AS 'en.text',
             c.[html_text_en] AS 'en.htmltext',
             c.[key_fr] AS 'fr.key',
             c.[text_fr] AS 'fr.text',
             c.[html_text_fr] AS 'fr.htmltext'
      FOR JSON PATH
     ) j(j);
```

Comment: Your solution returns an array per row. It should be an array of rows. I have updated my question to reflect that.